# Excel to Google spreadsheet - formula conversion

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, formula

I have the following formula that works out filtered by multiple conditions.

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS('List'!$H:$H,TRANSPOSE('Assignee'!$C2:$C6), 'List'!$U:$U, 'Proceed'!$B2:$B8)))}
```

So I converted to google sheeets formula using ARRAYFORMULA Function for array-evaluated but it doesn't worked.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIFS('List'!$H:$H,TRANSPOSE('Assignee'!$C2:$C6), 'List'!$U:$U, 'Proceed'!$B2:$B8))))
```

I made a sample document. [Open sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdR3IgtnQgs37FCufCDSC-Pyp7VF2YE5spZdlcfg7rI/edit?usp=sharing)

You can check a formula in the summary sheet.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Maybe you forgot to array-evaluate it?

Double click the cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> OR, wrap the whole formula with =ArrayFormula()

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIFS('List'!$H:$H,TRANSPOSE('Assignee'!$C2:$C6), 'List'!$U:$U, 'Proceed'!$B2:$B8))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply unfortunately it doesn't worked.

Comment: @user3725139 Can you give more details? Is it possible for you to share the google spreadsheet? (you can still unshare later on)

Comment: Thanks guys. I made a sample document. You can check a formula in the summary sheet. [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdR3IgtnQgs37FCufCDSC-Pyp7VF2YE5spZdlcfg7rI/edit#gid=494522759

Comment: @Roh Okay, I think this is a limitation on gspreadsheet's array version of COUNTIFS. I added two alternate ways to do the count. I don't know how you would make it more flexible in terms of increasing the range of your criteria though :(